# Replace css background image with Font Awesome icon

Tags: css, background-image, font-awesome

I know this should be easy but I don't know what I am doing wrong. I just want to replace a png background-image (css) with an Font Awesome icon.

This is the whole css file:

```css
.wc-bookings-date-picker .ui-datepicker{padding:0;width:auto;}
.wc-bookings-date-picker .ui-widget-content{border:0;background:#fff;-moz-box-shadow:0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.19);-webkit-box-shadow:0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.19);box-shadow:0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.19);}
.wc-bookings-date-picker .ui-datepicker-header{padding:0;overflow:hidden;text-transform:uppercase;border-radius:4px 4px 0 0;-webkit-border-radius:4px 4px 0 0;-moz-border-radius:4px 4px 0 0;background-color:#999;background-image:none;background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(bottom,#999 0,#aaa 100%);background-image:-o-linear-gradient(bottom,#999 0,#aaa 100%);background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(bottom,#999 0,#aaa 100%);background-image:linear-gradient(bottom,#999 0,#aaa 100%);border:0;border-top:1px solid #999;color:#fff;}
.wc-bookings-date-picker .ui-datepicker-header .ui-state-hover{background:0 0;border-color:transparent;cursor:pointer;}
.wc-bookings-date-picker .ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-title{line-height:1em;font-weight:400;padding:.75em 0;}
.wc-bookings-date-picker .ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-next,.wc-bookings-date-picker .ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-prev{top:-1px;background:#999;border-radius:0;font-weight:400;height:2.5em;width:2em;}
.wc-bookings-date-picker .ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-next.ui-state-hover,.wc-bookings-date-picker .ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-prev.ui-state-hover{background:#aaa;}
.wc-bookings-date-picker .ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-prev{left:0;border:0;}
.wc-bookings-date-picker .ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-next{right:0;border:0;}
.wc-bookings-date-picker .ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-next span,.wc-bookings-date-picker .ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-prev span{margin-top:-4px;top:40%;}
.wc-bookings-date-picker .ui-icon-circle-triangle-e{background-image:url(../images/ui-icons_ffffff_256x240.png);background-position:-32px 0;}
.wc-bookings-date-picker .ui-icon-circle-triangle-w{background-image:url(../images/ui-icons_ffffff_256x240.png);background-position:-96px 0;}
.wc-bookings-date-picker .ui-datepicker table{margin:0;}
.wc-bookings-date-picker .ui-datepicker th{padding:.75em 0;text-transform:uppercase;color:#bbb;font-weight:400;border-top:1px solid #e6e6e6;background:#fefefe;}
.wc-bookings-date-picker .ui-datepicker td{border:0;border-top:1px solid #e6e6e6;border-right:1px solid #e6e6e6;background:#fefefe;padding:0!important;}
.wc-bookings-date-picker .ui-datepicker td:last-child{border-right:0;}
.wc-bookings-date-picker .ui-datepicker td .ui-state-default{background:0 0;background-image:none!important;border:0;color:#2b2b2b;margin:0;font-weight:400;text-align:center;padding:.75em 0;}
.wc-bookings-date-picker .ui-datepicker td a.ui-state-active,.wc-bookings-date-picker .ui-datepicker td a.ui-state-active.ui-state-hover{background:#fefefe;color:#b2b2b2;background-image:none!important;}
.wc-bookings-date-picker .ui-datepicker td.fully_booked a,.wc-bookings-date-picker .ui-datepicker td.fully_booked span{background-color:#c0392b!important;background-image:none!important;border-color:rgba(0,0,0,.1)!important;color:#fff!important;text-shadow:0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.1);}
.wc-bookings-date-picker .ui-datepicker td.bookable a{background-color:#2ecc71!important;background-image:none!important;border-color:rgba(0,0,0,.1)!important;color:#fff!important;text-shadow:0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.1);}
.wc-bookings-date-picker .ui-datepicker td.partial_booked a{background-color:#2ecc71!important;background-image:none!important;border-color:rgba(0,0,0,.1)!important;color:#fff!important;text-shadow:0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.1);position:relative;z-index:1;}
.wc-bookings-date-picker .ui-datepicker td.partial_booked a:before{content:"";position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:0;height:0;border-top:2.5em solid #C96259;border-right:2.5em solid transparent;z-index:-10;opacity:.75;}
.wc-bookings-date-picker .ui-datepicker td.ui-datepicker-current-day a{background:#239e57!important;opacity:1!important;}
.wc-bookings-date-picker .ui-datepicker td.ui-datepicker-other-month{background:#eee;}
.wc-bookings-date-picker .ui-datepicker td.bookable-range .ui-state-default{background:#239e57;color:#fff;}
```

And the part that needs to be changed into Font Awesome icons is:

```
.wc-bookings-date-picker .ui-icon-circle-triangle-e{background-image:url(../images/ui-icons_ffffff_256x240.png);background-position:-32px 0;}
.wc-bookings-date-picker .ui-icon-circle-triangle-w{background-image:url(../images/ui-icons_ffffff_256x240.png);background-position:-96px 0;}
```

The css content for previous = "\f053"

The css content for n next = "\f054"

I feel really dumb :(

Comment: Can you add your HTML and include only the relevant CSS please.

Comment: You will likely need to do some markup work as well, since Font Awesome is an actual font comprised of text it cannot be used as a background persay but you can layer a couple divs if you so wish to make it appear as a background.

Answer (score 3):

This is not dumb. Icons from font-awesome might look similar to images but they do not work at all the same way.

More specifically, they work precisely like text. As such, you cannot benefit all the functions associated with background images, that can fit / stretch the container.

As it is a font, you cannot use it in background. Fortunately, you can still make it appear with pseudo elements.

The solution would be like this:

```
.wc-bookings-date-picker .ui-icon-circle-triangle-e,  .wc-bookings-date-picker .ui-icon-circle-triangle-w {
    position: relative;
}

.wc-bookings-date-picker .ui-icon-circle-triangle-e::before {
    content: "\f053";
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    /* Put here the height of the image */
    font-size: 240px;
    position: absolute;
    left: -32px;
    top:0;
}

.wc-bookings-date-picker .ui-icon-circle-triangle-w::before {
    content: "\f054";
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    /* Put here the height of the image */
    font-size: 240px;
    position: absolute;
    left: -96px;
    top:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to first reset them and ensure they set a new positioning context:

```
.wc-bookings-date-picker .ui-icon-circle-triangle-e,
.wc-bookings-date-picker .ui-icon-circle-triangle-w { 
    background:none; 
    position:relative;
}
```

Then reapply rules to use the new versions (you can guess the other one):

```
.wc-bookings-date-picker .ui-icon-circle-triangle-w:before {
    content:"\f054";
    font-family:FontAwesome;
    left:0;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
}
```

Some additional positioning may be required depending on the original CSS.